# Performance overhead of virtual inheritance if only one base has data members

Tags: c++, g++

Virtual inheritance can come with a performance overhead when the offset to a base class needs to be calculated at runtime.

```
class A {...};
class B : virtual public A {...}
class C : virtual public A {...}
class D : virtual public B, virtual public C {...}
```

Will any offset be calculated at runtime if in the above hierarchy the only class that has data members is "A" and none of the classes have virtual functions. (so the offset to any base class should be zero.)

(I'm trying to design a hierarchy of container classes where "A" has the data pool and all meta-data needed and has a minimal functionality. "B" and "C" extend that functionality and "D" has all the functionality. It's important that I can cast from a reference to D to a reference to B or C or A. Since the elements in the containers will be accessed frequently it should have best possible performance. I'm trying to find a better design but if there is no overhead in this case then my problem would be solved.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset will still be calculated because you can always add more classes that would require it.

```
class F: public class E, virtual public A { };

class G: public class F, virtual public D { };
```

In this case, the `class A` data can be in a different location than it would be when just using `class D`.

There are also issues with the vtable pointer.  Each subobject (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) has distinct vtables, and when calling those functions each will need the correct offset to locate the data in `A`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to design such a hierarchy of classes is to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). To this end, the data are actually stored in the final class, but the functionality is provided in the base class. The idea is to separate the concepts of functionality and storage, allowing the same functionality for observing containers, containers on the heap or on the stack etc.

```
template<typename T, typename Derived>
struct functionality
{
  using value_type = T;
  value_type&operator[](size_t i) { return data()[i]; }
  /* ... */
  value_type*data()
  { return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->_m_data(); }
  const value_type*data() const
  { return static_cast<const Derived*>(this)->_m_data(); }
};
```

and then

```
template<typename T>
struct container : functionality<T,container<T>>
{
  using base = functionality<T,container<T>>;
  using base::operator[];
  using base::data;
  /* ... */
  T* _m_data() { return buffer->get(); }
  const T* _m_data() const { return buffer->get(); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<T[]> buffer;    // data on the heap
};
```